# Usage of "On" vs "About"

Tags: word-usage

In a recent history essay, I wrote the following sentence:
"As banks began to fail, the regional banks were divided **on** whether to assist all banks or only member banks."
My teacher corrected the "on", explaining that it should be replaced with "about".

So, is he correct?
Thanks,
~Hom

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=divided+on+whether%2Cdivided+over+whether%2Cdivided+about+whether&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdivided%20on%20whether%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdivided%20over%20whether%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdivided%20about%20whether%3B%2Cc0) would seem to imply that there's a free choice.  But people may be divided over the preferableness of these usages.

Comment: But, preferences aside, surely the teacher was wrong to 'correct' it?

Comment: Teachers get to be "right", even when they are "wrong": *De gustibus non est disputandum*. Even if there's no benefit arguing English with your history teacher, you know that there was actually no problem with your language.

Comment: @ScotM Very true xD, but my teacher will give me my points back if I provide convincing evidence that "on" was acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from where Edwin Ashworth has left, I will show you the links for these core expressions at Google Books:

["divided **on** whether to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22divided%20on%20whether%20to%20%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22divided%20on%20whether%20to%22)
About 18,600 results

["divided **over** whether to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22divided+on+whether+to+%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22divided+over+whether+to%22)
About 19,500 results

["divided **about** whether to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22divided%20on%20whether%20to%20%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22divided%20about%20whether%20to%22)
About 3,320 results

**The first two use the "official" collocations for "to divide," i.e. "on," and "over,"** the only ones mentioned say by The BBI Dictionary of English Word Combinations. However, my edition is 1997, things might have changed since.

They are also the most frequent.

However, the relatively large numbers of examples with "about," in books that have been written by native speakers clearly of outstanding education (professors, etc.), and which have certainly been checked by some of the most capable editors, indicate that this usage is growing in acceptance, and **I for one would not reject it**.

Comment: I would add another... "divided as to whether" which had 10,600 hits. All versions have essentially the same meaning and I think the teacher was pretty picky to mark yours as wrong. I think your sentence was quite good.